# Injecting new instance of Service declared in deps of custom service provider in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-services

Basicallly I am trying to create a module that has a list component, which I want to reuse.

The list component get's a service (service B) injected in its constructor:`constructor(@Optional() private listService?: ServiceB) {}`

There also exists another service (service A) with a constructor: `constructor(private is: ServiceB) {}`

,which in turn is used to comunicate with components who are using the list component.

ServiceA is exported as a provider function to hide the existance of Service B:

```js
export let ListServiceProvider = {
  provide: ServiceA,
  useFactory: (is: ServiceB) => new ServiceA(is),
  deps: [ServiceB]
};
```

What i want to achieve is that every list component would get its own set of services where Service A gets injected into the outside component, while ServiceB gets injected both in service A AND in the list component itself.

As for now, Service A gets created for every list component, but Service B is shared for all instances Service A.

How to achieve the above?

The data flow would then be: Parent component <-> ServiceA <-> Service B <-> List component.